# Remove whitespace at the beginning of a text

Tags: html, angular, forms, whitespace

I'm currently working with a reactive form; basically the user should not enable the send information(enable save button) if the input data is incorrect(sended whit whitespaces). In this sense, for the name, I require that the user cannot start his name with a space, but allow spaces after letters have been entered, I currently have restriction of special characters and numbers in the same field. I have found solutions related to Trim I tried to implemented it, but field validation is not done in "real time", just after clicking on save button is getting the "error". Any help will be of great help to me

This is mi html code

```
    form nz-form class="toppart" (ngSubmit)="sendUserData()" [formGroup]="createForm" autocomplete="off">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row my-3">
                  <div class="col col-3">
                    <label> Name <small>*</small></label>
                    <nz-form-item>
                      <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Please input your name!">
                        <nz-input-group>
                          <!-- (ngModelChange)="nameChange()" -->
                          <input formControlName="name" nz-input placeholder="Enter Name"
                            onkeypress='return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || (event.charCode == 32) )' required />
                        </nz-input-group>
                      </nz-form-control>
                    </nz-form-item>
                  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Form in typescript

```
public createForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    email: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    password: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    created_by: new FormControl(''),
    role: new FormControl([],Validators.required),
  });
```

This shouldn't happen: Those spaces should be removed as they get and should not appear visually

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a custom validator

```
public noWhitespaceValidator(control: FormControl) {
    const isWhitespace = (control.value || '').trim().length === 0;
    const isValid = !isWhitespace;
    return isValid ? null : { 'whitespace': true };
}
```

and pass that to form control

```
new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.noWhitespaceValidator]);
```

in html

```
<span *ngIf="createForm.controls.name.hasError('whitespace')">Name Cannot contain only spaces</span>
```

this will show error if name field contains only spaces

**or if you want to remove spaces in real time instead of showing error, you can use valuechanges**

```
this.createForm.controls.name.valueChanges().subscribe(res = {
    this.createForm.controls.name.setValue((res || '').trim());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a regex pattern to your field. This will allow validation while typing.

> Validators.pattern(^[^-\s][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]+$)

Refer: [Form Validators Pattern](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern)

Comment: Thank you Saloo, your answer is correct, but it does not allow me to enter blanks at any time, so it does not fit what is required, anyway thank you for your appreciation :)